# HTML5 Video Not Working in JBOSS EAP 7.1.0

Tags: html, tomcat, servlets, jboss-eap-7

Problem Definition

I have a simple web app with html5 video on index page. When i try to deploy this web application on jboss eap 7.1.0 in stand alone mode it does not display video. But when i run the same web app on tomcat it runs perfectly fine and display video in browser.

Googled Solution

I have researched for the problem and found that i need to add mime type tag to my web.xml and to standalone.xml. Also i need to add range header to standlone.xml.But Still the problem exist.

Web.xml Content

```
<display-name>EAPDemo</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>mp4</extension>
    <mime-type>video/mp4</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

standalone.xml Content

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default" />
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="range" />
            <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
        <mime-mappings>
            <mime-mapping name="mp4" value="video/mp4" />
        </mime-mappings>        
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers> 
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="JBoss-EAP/7"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        <expression-filter name="range" expression="byte-range(send-accept-ranges=true)" />
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

Video Not Playing Screen Shot
[image: Video Not Playing Screen Shot]

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post the pertinent section of the web.xml file that you modified as well as what you modified in standalone.xml

Comment: I have edited the post and added the web.xml content and standalone.xml content

Comment: @AbhayChoksi Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Didnt you hit https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-1444 ?